# facing an issue while compiling code that uses C++ map

Tags: c++, dictionary, stl

I have the following code :

```
std::map<
    const CosTransactions::otid_t,
     std::pair<
        CosTransactions::otid_t,
        CosTransactions::Coordinator_ptr>,
    otid_t_less> XID_Broker_impl::cache;
```

when compiling the above code I am getting an error as follows:

```
D:/Y24\usr\include/xmemory", line 144: error(483): function
          "std::allocator<_Ty>::address(std::_Allocator_base<_Ty>::value_type
          &) const [with _Ty=const CosTransactions::otid_t]" has already been
          declared
          detected during:
            instantiation of class
```

I am using HP-Nonstop C++ compiler? when I remove the "const" of key in map , the error goes away. Does this means that I cannot use "const key" in map?
Please help me on this question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From C++11  §23.3.1 *Class template map*

```
For a map<Key,T> the key_type is Key and the value_type is pair <const Key,T>
```

Note here key type is `const` by definition, which implies that you shouldn't declare the key type as `const` again.